# Prevent GSON from Adding Null when Deserializing JSON

Tags: android, json, gson

I am using GSON (Scarlet GSON) to parse objects that I got from the server (web socket) into two types: `TypeA` and `TypeB`:

```
data class TypeA(
    val id: UUID,
    val name: String,
    val number1: Int,
)
```

```
data class TypeB(
    val id: UUID,
    val name: String,
    val number1: Int,
    val number2: Int,
    val number3: Int,
)
```

```
interface ScarletApi {
    @Receive
    fun observe TypeA(): Flowable<TypeA>
    @Receive
    fun observe TypeB(): Flowable<TypeB>
}
```

My Scarlet builder looks like this:

```
val scarlet = Scarlet.Builder()
    // ...
    .addMessageAdapterFactory(GsonMessageAdapter.Factory())
    .build()
```

However, whenever I have an object from the server sent to the client, GSON always tries to decode for both types.

If the server sends TypeA, GSON will automatically add `null` to missing fields (`number2`, `number3`) when decoding for TypeB.

And if the server sends TypeB, GSON will automatically decode for TypeA as well.

Such behaviors from GSON are confirmed from [Gson User Guide](https://github.com/google/gson/blob/master/UserGuide.md#TOC-Gson-With-Maven).

> While deserializing, a missing entry in JSON results in setting the corresponding field in the object to its default value: null for object types, zero for numeric types, and false for booleans.

How do I prevent GSON from doing such, and only decode for objects that exactly match the mapping? Much appreciation!

Comment: The question is very vague, to be honest (and it's also unclear which part of the Gson User Guide you're referring so the question could be more clear), and it sounds like you create a `TypeB` object at the server side, but receive it at the client side by using the `TypeA` endpoint that is declared to accept `TypeA` objects only (and I still don't believe I "parsed" your question correct).

Comment: Thanks for letting me know. I have edited my post, and hopefully it's more clear now.

Comment: If I understand your question correctly now, then you cannot "fix" this: if your local (client) object class is declared with `foo`, `bar`, and `baz`, and if your remote (server) object is declared with `bar` (only), and the transferred representation in JSON is `{"bar":"123"}`, then it's totally expected behavior: Gson by default only injects directly mapped fields regardless the "receiver" structure (therefore `foo` and `baz` are left intact and retain as `null`, their default value after `new`). Well, this is how static type system in Java works.

Comment: If you need a very strict rule, say "the transferring object must contain all fields", then you need implementing a custom type deserializer that checks whether all fields were mapped from the transferred object properties (not that very easy/flexible to track that in Gson, but doable). This also implies you must be sure that your local endpoint receives objects of that very structure (mapped to that very class in your local) and nominally _the same class_, and never polymorphic (actually, what I thought about it yesterday).

Comment: To me, it sounds like you're facing something (to some extent) special to Java/Gson, but it probably could be revised and probably your entire approach changes, or your question could describe your problem more widely, not very focusing on that "special" Gson behavior (that still works as expected).

Comment: Thanks for sharing!! I have found a workaround though. But it's just more elegant to me if it's easier to change the behaviors in GSON.